# Cant reach mongo db container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I trying to implement a dockerized mongo/node based app by this [article](https://medium.com/statuscode/dockerising-a-node-js-and-mongodb-app-d22047e2806f).

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  gecar_app:
    build: 
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.gecars
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    command: /usr/app/initAndStartService.sh
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Dockerfile.gercars

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY src/ /usr/app/src/
COPY package.json /usr/app/package.json
COPY webpack.config.js /usr/app/webpack.config.js
COPY tsconfig.json /usr/app/tsconfig.json
COPY initAndStartService.sh /usr/app/initAndStartService.sh
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/app/initAndStartService.sh"]
```

initAndStartService.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
curl 127.0.0.1:27017
```

but when run `docker-compose up` get this:

```
mongo        | 2019-11-19T06:13:21.682+0000 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Listening on 0.0.0.0
mongo        | 2019-11-19T06:13:21.683+0000 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

...................

```
gecar_app_1  |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 27017: Connection refused
```

If I recognize the situation correctly, `gecar_app_1` container can`t reach`mongo` container.

Answer (score 0):

> depends_on
>
> Express dependency between services, Service dependencies cause the
>   following behaviors:
>
> ```
> docker-compose up starts services in dependency order. In the following example, db and redis are started before web.
>
> docker-compose up SERVICE automatically includes SERVICE’s dependencies. In the following example, docker-compose up web also
> ```
>
> creates and starts db and redis.
>
> ```
> docker-compose stop stops services in dependency order. In the following example, web is stopped before db and redis.
> ```

in other words, when you want to communicate with the mongo container, all you have to do is to call it as `mongo` based on your container service naming.

So `curl mongo:27017` from the **gecar_app** container will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is a loopback address, this mean, when you run `curl 127.0.0.1:27017` on `gecar_app` container, you try to connect to itself, but `gecar_app` did not have any service running on `27017` port. What you need to connect is `mongo` service (I think so).

You use `depends_on` to wait until the `mongo` service started, then start the `gecar_app` container (good point), now `mongo` will be come to a hostname, and `gecar_app` can connect to `mongo` via `mongo` "domain".

But, `gecar_app` maybe started before mongodb service already, then you have make sure that when `mongo` service already. You can use `healthcheck` property to do that.

Finally,
`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  gecar_app:
    build: 
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.gecars
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    command: /usr/app/initAndStartService.sh
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo mongo:27017/test --quiet 1
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

and, `initAndStartService.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
curl mongo:27017
```